# Por que transformar absolutamente tudo em Classes no PHP?

Tags: php, classes

Meus sistemas tanto em ASP, Delphi e PHP mantém um padrão meio antigo (procedural) no modo de programar, pois acho entedioso programar da forma como é hoje, vejo muitos ou senão todos usando Classes, Objects e afins em rotinas tão simples e tornam a manutenção um fardo pelo menos pra mim, sei que o melhor é acompanhar o mercado para não ficar para traz, e estou fazendo isso procurando entender melhor sobre classes e seu aliados, rs, hoje faço uso de Templates no PHP e Heranças no Delphi e procuro separar as rotinas e funções comuns em Units, deixando o código o mais legível possível.

Claro que faço uso de algumas classes inclusive de terceiros que facilitam a vida, confesso que não procuro entender o que o usuário quis fazer e sim se funciona, pois meu tempo está muito escasso.

Mas me aprofundando em classes na web, vi que alguns assim como eu muitos relutam em fazer uso 100% de classes, deixando somente para casos em que o código fica enorme numa rotina.

O Netbeans por exemplo sugere que uma função não tenha mais que 20 linhas, estou longe de atingir um grau qualquer de um programador do Netbeans, mas fico pensando, se eu desmembrar minhas funções a cada 20 linhas meus arquivos vão ficar muito fragmentados, e a leitura desses será horrível.

Vou procurar não tomar partido sobre se é bom ou não, tenho lido que classes são mais lentas que procedural (achei estranho), por sua vez tenho visto que classe é largamente usado, isso por si só já mostra que pode ser melhor.

Fazendo minhas comparações não consegui ver vantagem real do uso de classes em sistemas não tão complexos, tenho visto que muitos programadores usam classe por exemplo num simples Insert, Select, Delete tornando uma simples execução em um emaranhado de códigos, onde uma simples função resolveria o problema.

Vou pegar como exemplo o PHP, sei que  muitas funções internas fazem uso de classes, mas pra usar elas preciso realmente fazer uso também?

O Uso de classes não seria para organizar o código, não seria melhor deixar o uso de classes para criar objetos, por exemplo de conexão, ou algum calculo complexo, assim como são feitos com DLLs diversas e Componentes no Delphi e outras?

Eu sinceramente e honestamente estou querendo ser convencido de que devo fazer uso constante de classes assim como tenho vistos nos códigos PHP que tenho pego.

Vejam só estou estudando classes e espero compreender e fazer bom uso delas, não entendam esse post como critica e sim como uma discussão que possa render bons frutos tanto a mim como aqueles que lerem.

Comment: E pra que você faria isto? É o oposto do que deveria fazer. Faça o certo e seja feliz, não vá atrás de bobões que não sabem o que estão fazendo. O tempo das pessoas é escasso porque ela gasta muito tempo tentando arrumar os erros que comete porque não se qualifica adequadamente, porque usa ferramentas inadequadas e aí precisa fazer um monte de trabalho extra para fazer isto funcionar em vez de usar o simples e correto. Sem saber muito bem o que é e como usar OOP certo, é melhor não usar (e quase todo mundo usa errado).

Comment: Sugestões como a do Netbeans não fazem o menor sentido e servem só para agradar leigos. 1 linha pode ser grande demais, e 200 pode não ser. De forma geral não sei de onde vem essa ideia que classe são mais lentas. Deve ser mais um dos mitos que existem por aí. Mais lentas em relação ao que? É possível em alguma comparação, mas se quer velocidade não use PHP. Sua visão parece estar acima da média, exceto por ouvir mitos. A maioria parte do uso de classes não precisa, especialmente em PHP. Organizar códigos em uma linguagem de *script*? Faz 30 anos que uso OOP e não aprendi tudo o que deveria.

Comment: Você acha que é fácil? Só é para quem decidiu fazer do jeito que estava em algum livro e não se importa em fazer errado. A maioria das pessoas usam classes para satisfazerem seu ego e dizer que estão na crista da onda.

Comment: Pois é Maniero, eu nunca gostei de ir na onda da massa, sempre me retive ao simples e funcional e dessa forma vou levando a vida, mas sabe aquele momento em que você para e diz, preciso me atualizar, e ai recomeçam as auto-criticas, não sou um programador de auto nível, mas pelo menos tudo que me pediram até hoje consegui resolver com o que já sei, mas as vezes pego uns códigos "estrangeiros" e fico meio perdido, por isso a necessidade de saber pelo menos um pouco.

Comment: Quanto a dizer que classe é mais lento, em teoria eu até concordo, se o processador precisa dar mais passos pra executar uma tarefa, tecnicamente será mais lento, imagine o processador criando N objetos, setando valores pra depois usa-las, alguns códigos em classe que vejo é como se o programador quisesse ir no vizinho da direita dando a volta no quarteirão pela esquerda, acho que nesse ponto que entra sua visão, o cara está fazendo errado então fica mais lento, concordo, então pra usar classes tem que ter uma analise muito mas muito minunciosa.

Comment: Isso. Falo muito sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20%5borienta%c3%a7%c3%a3o-a-objetos%5d OOP é difícil fazer certo.

Comment: Não esta funcionando o link

Comment: eu acho o maior erro/equivocuo pensar que OO é solução/melhor, em linguagens aonde pode simplificar as coisas criar classe para qualquer coisinha é um baita exagero, eu simplesmente sigo basicamente a regrinha "isto me será útil ou mais fácil assim, então o faço". Tem códigos que simplesmente procedurais de umas 5 linhas em um arquivo php resolvem todo um problema, tem código que dependendo das regras de negócios separar em camadas será melhor, não tem como definir cada caso é um caso, é tudo relativo.

Comment: Não importa o quanto lhe digam que OO é _overrated_, você sentirá necessidade de estar na crista da onda, essa vontade irá te consumir, te minar e acabará com sua capacidade de design de soluções, você não saberá mais o que é certo e errado e afundará em um mar de _hype_, metodologias e boas práticas! Me soltem! Soltem! Injeção não! ..... Mas falando sério, se for estudar OOP procure estudar direito, evite aplicar herança desnecessariamente, dê preferência a composição e outras _cositas mas_.

Comment: Acho que estou com maturidade para evitar a questão "crista da onda", minha idade já não é favorável a enfrentar o mercado de trabalho com unhas e dentes, minhas ideias consistem em apresentar soluções simples e que de o retorno necessário ao cliente sem alardes, tipo "essa solução vai resolver sua vida!!!", acho que a sobriedade vai trazer menos estresse para mim  e o cliente, mesmo que isso me custe algumas perdas de trabalho, estou dando prioridade a vida, tanto que mudei pro interior, meu estresse estava me matando aos poucos, por isso quero aplicar classes onde realmente seja necessário.

Comment: @Marcelo que bom, eu tenho 48 anos e tenho dificuldade (mas resisto :) ) Não é fácil adotar ou rejeitar algo. E é fácil decidir errado. Geralmente só se percebe depois que decidiu errado, e isto já é uma sorte, a maioria não percebe.